# How can I isolate part of a string in a list of strings and sort the list with it? (in Python)

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to write a program to plot lots of graphs for me in Python and my data all has the same name format:

info_scan1.csv, info_scan2.csv, info_scan3.csv, etc., where info is a different string for each file.

I need to plot the data in pairs, i.e., have scan 1 and 2 on the same plot, scan 3 and 4, scan 5 and 6 etc.  So I want to sort the list of filenames by the `int` after 'scan'.  How do I do that?

I'm using `list = os.listdir(os.curdir)` to put all the file names in a list.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you expecting us to write code for you? What have you tried? Can you show samples of your non-working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all files from current directory:

```
files = [x for x in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(x)]
```

So `files` is a list of file names from directory `.`. Then you have to sort this list by numbers in the middle of filename, I see this solution:

```
files.sort(key=lambda f: int(re.search("(\d+)", f).group(1)))
```

This numerically sorts in-place `files` list using numbers in file name. Then you should take two values in this list in a loop. [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module has recipes and one of them is `grouper function:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *arg)
```

So you can do:

```
>>> for f in grouper(files, 2):
...    print f # f here is a tuple of two files. f[0] is the first and f[1] is the second one
... 
('info_scan1.csv', 'info_scan2.csv')
('info_scan3.csv', 'info_scan4.csv')
('info_scan5.csv', 'info_scan6.csv')
('info_scan7.csv', 'info_scan8.csv')
('info_scan9.csv', 'info_scan12.csv')
('info_scan57.csv', 'info_scan58.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filenames have the same digit precision (if `scan09.csv`, not `scan9.csv`, precedes `scan10.csv`) then a simple `list.sort()` would do it. If not, then what you want to do is called a "natural sort": google for python recipes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
name_list = ['_scan1.csv','_scan7.csv','_scan3.csv']

f = lambda s: int(s.replace('.csv','').replace('_scan',''))

sorted(name_list,key = f)
['_scan1.csv', '_scan3.csv', '_scan7.csv']
```